# create image of application and store to database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have create a application in c#. What my problem was when user try to edit something new to database via this application, it will not save to main table in database directly, but will store on another table, and waiting for another user to approve it.

In this case, if user try to edit, I wish to save the application image and store to the table, and when another user come and approve it, it can show different before edit and after edit, this is much convenience for user to view and make decision.

I have search through internet, but I can not find a good solution to solve this problem, anyone can help please.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you just have to save a NEW copy everytime a user makes an edit? You can create a field to store version numbers of  each copy so you can keep track of which copy is newer.

Comment: @failedprogramming I created another table to store all activity of user done before it get approve in that table ,not only for edit. 
exp(add/edit/delete)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are different approaches to your question.

For instance you can imitate the "posting" and "signing"techniques used in many accounting and/or Point of Sales systems (such as AccPac, PsManager, QuickBooks, Rx-Solution, Pastel, UniSove etc).

Generally the approach does Not involve having a temporary store / cache of data either in your DB or system Registry - No!

What happens is actually storing the user1 data in any case - before the signing / posting by the supervisor / administrator. All you have to do is:

1. Introduce/add some columns (acting as flags) such as "lastUpdatedBy_, latsUpdateDate_, createdBy_, createdDate_, posted_boolean, postedDate, postedByStr etc)
2. at the application, have controls (buttons etc) to allow "posting" function (func that updates these columns in table)

   2.1 your normal Save() fucntion should not include updating these columns

   2.1.1 have another PostRecord() function that explicitly updates these columns.

   2.1.2 ONLY supervisors /administrators (by login credentials and access permissions) can fire this PostRecord)()    - through the controls

   2.2 the controls are visible / enable only when supervisor /admin is logged in
    2.2.1 the controls Not visible /enabled if that recordset (current position in binding) already has column "posted_boolean" = true.

Generally something like that.

As for the BEFORE Vs AFTER status of the record, you need created a log table for each table e.g. an "OrdersEditHistory" table for "Orders" table.
From this you can log the two instances:

- before : fired just before actual PostRecord() func . It captures the state of the record.
- after: fired after firing  PostRecord(). This is optional as you can still retrieve the details from the actual main table and do your comparison.

I hope this helps. Chagbert.